# Can't build Xamarin Forms, Android project, TargetFrameworkVersion v9.0 not is not supported

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-sdk-manager

Trying to build a Xamarin Forms Android project.  The Minimum Android Version and Target Android Version are set to "Android 8.1 (Api Level 27 - Oreo) in the project Properties.

Under the SDK Manager, I have API Level Versions (SDK Platforms) 21-28 installed.

When loading the project, I get the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Project MyProjMobile.Android cannot build using TargetFrameworkVersion v9.0 because it s not supported. Please change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is supported.          0

No matter what I set the TargetFramwork settings to (I tried lowering them), I continue to get the same error.

I have even tried loading this project after deleting the bin, obj and packages folders with no luck.

You can look at my manifest here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dnp6qqknbbn5ee/AndroidManifest.xml?dl=0

Any ideas?

Comment: "TargetFrameworkVersion" is not the same is "Target Android Version" is set in the manifest, it is the (Xamarin.Android) version used to compile against :https://stackoverflow.com/a/49248192/4984832

Comment: I have provided a link to my manifest. Thoughts?

Comment: the error is NOT about the runtime API levels that are set in your manifest, it is about the API target that you are using to compile your Xamarin.Android application against. Review the link in my first comment