# Xamarin.Forms - firebase is not compatible with monoandroid81?

Tags: android, forms, firebase, xamarin

when i try to install "App center push" nuget package, this require Xamarin.firebase.messaging
and when i try to install  Xamarin.firebase.messaging , show me this error

For resolution, i try to change target framework of android , but not working.

Can you help me? this is the error:

```
The package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 71.1740.0 is not compatible with
monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). The package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 71.1740.0 support: 
monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)
```

Comment: Did you change the Android API level settings or the Xamarin.Android version? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246580/xamarin-how-to-update-mono-android-version-to-resolve-dependencies/49248192#49248192

Comment: @SushiHangover yes , i have change to android pie (9.0) level api 28 , but not working

Comment: But which one are you changing, the `Target Android Version` which is the Android API **runtime** level (not the one that causes your error), but the Xamarin.Android **compile** `Target Framework` which is causing your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue when my Target Framework version is Android 8.1.

I then double-click **Android Properties**, choose **Application** tab, and set **Compile using Android version: (Target Framework)** as Android 9.0.

Then you go to **Android Manifest** tab, will find the **Target Android Version** (in **Android Manifest**) also become Android 9.0, now you can install Xamarin.firebase.messaging for Android project, it works fine.

[image]

### Update

If the **Target Android version** is not Android 9.0 when you have change **Compile using Android Version: (Target Framework)**, you can change this as Android 9.0, then see if still having same issue.

[image]

Comment: After i compile with target framework as android 9.0 , i don't find target android version in android manifest !

Comment: @Ciro,After you select **Compile using Android version:(Target Framework)** as Android 9.0, you can select Android Manifest tab, sliding down, you will see it. Please take a look my update.