# Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser 1.4.0.1 is not compatible with monoandroid10.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I get this error message in Visual Studio for Mac Community 8.10.21 (build 4) when I want to update my nuget packages in my Android project: Could not update packages.

> Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser 1.4.0.1 with MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0.
> Package Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser 1.4.0.1 is not compatible with monoandroid10.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0). Package Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser 1.4.0.1 supports:

- monoandroid12.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0)
- net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

Incompatible packages: 5

[nuget packages image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZIKR.png)

How can I update the 5 nuget packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, you need to update your monoandroid10.0 to monoandroid12.0.

So you can set the Target Framework in your project as android 12.0 and then try to update the nuget packages.

If you need more information, please check the following link:
[Xamarin - How to update Mono.Android version to resolve dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246580/xamarin-how-to-update-mono-android-version-to-resolve-dependencies)