# How to update MonoAndroid version Xamarin Forms Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-6.0

I tried updating my project from netstandard2.0 to net6.0 by changing MobileApp.csprj file line:

```
 <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

To

```
 <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

Now I get errors:

```
Project '..\MobileApp\MobileApp.csproj' targets 'net6.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0'
```

How do I resolve this? I tried changing version to 13.0 manually in

```
<Reference Include="Mono.Android">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v13.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
```

But Visual Studio even after reopening it gives same error. So how do I resolve this?
I tried updating my project in first place bacause I wasnt able to use some NuGet packages because of older version.

Comment: Does this link [Xamarin - How to update Mono.Android version to resolve dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246580/xamarin-how-to-update-mono-android-version-to-resolve-dependencies) answered your question?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT No because I dont know where to.find those settings that are show in pictures. On project properties I see only Common properties and Configuration properties but they have just few settings, nothing like in those screenshots

Comment: Can you see the `Targetframeworkversion` in your Android.csproj file?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT It is pasted in a question, if we are talking about the same thing? this code snippet shows version: <Reference Include="Mono.Android">

Comment: You can set the Targetframeworkversion  to 13.0 in the Droid.csproj file.